# Modal over another modal

Tags: popup, modal, modal-view

we have a new feature annoucement pop up which comes once to the user on our dashboard.
when we speak about new feature it is ideal to show the the demo video as well i feel.
so we have inluded a video pop up over the main pop up. Is this is right way of doing? or is this against the laws of good UX?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a good pattern,
This is not a problem here, but acessibility readers can't interact with modals.

I think you should to try be less invasive, show a Modal and ask the user if he/she want to learn about the new feature, if he/she want redirect to a "langing page", with the informations, like the figma!

Comment: It seems you can make modals screen-reader friendly (this [article](https://developer.yoast.com/blog/the-a11y-monthly-making-modals-accessible/)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't use popups at all?
You could announce a new feature in way better and less invasive ways.

For example you could use a tiny banner that moves out above the page after opening it.

Give the user the option to make the announcement disappear by clicking an "X" or "Don't show again".

You could also introduce a new feature when a user is on the page of said feature by highlighting the action and explaining the feature in a onboarding type of style.

As above the user should be in control so give him the option to skip.